# Fiber handler accepting requests for the wrong content type

Tags: go, go-fiber

I'm building a simple RESTful API using [Fiber](https://gofiber.io/) `2.44.0` and [Go](https://go.dev/) `1.20`. I'm currently testing if I can enforce the *acceptable* content for a given handler (something very common), but it looks like I'm doing something wrong, or `fiber.Ctx.Accepts` doesn't quite work the way I'm expecting.

This is a very simple route I have defined. Notice the usage of `ctx.Accepts`...but it doesn't really matter what `Accept` HTTP header I use, all requests go through.

```golang
// app.go
func main() {
    config := fiber.Config{
        StrictRouting: true,
    }
    app := fiber.New(config)
    app.Use(logger.New(), recover.New())

    app.Get("/", handlers.RootHandler)

    log.Fatal(app.Listen(":8080"))
}

// ============================================================================

// handlers/handlers.go
func RootHandler(ctx *fiber.Ctx) error {
    ctx.Accepts(fiber.MIMETextPlain, fiber.MIMETextPlainCharsetUTF8)
    ctx.Set(fiber.HeaderContentType, ctx.GetReqHeaders()[fiber.HeaderAccept])
    return ctx.Status(fiber.StatusOK).SendString("Hello, world!")
}
```

Is there a way to avoid such behavior and configure the handlers/routes properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature of the func is:

```golang
func (c *Ctx) Accepts(offers ...string) string
```

It will return the acceptable offer from the offers you pass into this func. If the `Accept` header in the request does not match any one of the offers, it returns an empty string (see the [implementation](https://github.com/gofiber/fiber/blob/9d8eba55d65bbdc020b32e1cbf51640f2a63a074/helpers.go#L263-L298)). So if you want to enforce the acceptable content for a given handler, you can simply check whether the return value is an empty string:

```golang
func RootHandler(ctx *fiber.Ctx) error {
    if offer := ctx.Accepts(fiber.MIMETextPlain, fiber.MIMETextPlainCharsetUTF8); offer == "" {
        return ctx.SendStatus(fiber.StatusNotAcceptable)
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Great! I was looking at it and I thought I had to do such things but I was really hoping to find something like the approach from `Flamego`, where you can attach `Headers("Accept", "text/plain")` to a given route/operation, and it automatically matches the route if all header matches are successful...but I guess that might be something for the future in `Fiber`. Thanks!

Comment: In my opinion, the current behavior is reasonable. Because most of the time, the handler need to check the acceptable offer and serialize the response content accordingly. We will write code like this: `switch offer { case "json": /* marshal as json */; case "xml": /* marshal as xml */; default: /* StatusNotAcceptable */ }`.

Comment: I see. I'm quite used to the "frameworks world" where the defaults could be slightly different. `Fiber` behaves more like `Vert.x` (in the Java arena) rather than a framework...but for instance, in this case, an `HTTP 406` makes more sense. In `Spring Boot` (and friends) this would result in an `HTTP 404` by default. I need to look more into examples, and finally get used to do things more programmatically — ergo: pay attention to the implementations :)